# In Rails, how do I write a link_to expression that results in a "/path/id" format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5, link-to

This question is for Rails 5.  I have a model

```
class Vote < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :person
```

and then a config/routes.rb file that contains

```
  resources :votes
```

The issue is I want to create a path

```
/vote/person_id
```

in which "person_id" is actually the ID of a  person object and not a vote object.  I thought I could write a "link_to" expression like the below to achieve this

```
<%= link_to person.name, votes_path(person), :class => 'unvotedPersonLink' %>
```

but instead what's happening is the link that's generated is

```
/votes.11
```

How do I adjust my "link_to" or routes file so taht I can generate a link in the format I want?

Comment: `vote_path`, not `votes_path`. Do `rake routes`, and you'll see that `votes_path` doesn't expect an `:id`.

Comment: Oh good call.  That was indeed the problem.

Comment: @Natalia `votes_path(id: person)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see all routes, you should run `rails routes` command. Your vote resource like the below:

```
votes_path returns /votes
new_vote_path returns /votes/new
edit_vote_path(:id) returns /votes/:id/edit 
vote_path(:id) returns /votes/:id
```

You can see more info about Rails routes in the following link:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

this might solve the routing problem.

routes.rb

> resources :votes, param: :person_id

view

> votes_path(person_id: person.id)

Answer (score 0):

In your views you need to pass person id as below:

```
votes_path(person: person)
```

Or like this:

```
votes_path(person, @vote)
```

Or :

```
votes_path(person: current_user)
```

Also, if you want to use the person id to add vote I would recommend you to inject the person id through controller using current_user